# Why Borderlands2 run on my new gaming system fine at the store but not at home?

Tags: pc, borderlands-2

I recently built a gaming system with the following components:

Intel Core I5-4690K,
MSI Z97-Gaming ATX LGA 1150 motherboard,
16 Gigs RAM,
GIGABYTE GTX970 Graphics Gard,
Intel 730 SSD Drive, Windows 8 OS

When hardwired or wirelessly connected to the internet when I start Borderland2 the cpu runs at 100% as do all other games.  I brought the machine back to Micro Center. They did a diagnostic and couldn't find any reason for the CPU to run high. In fact at Micro Center it runs fine.  They're convinced its my environment. I swapped out different monitors just to try something which made no difference.  No other processes are using the CPU other than the game.  If I can't fix this I'll have to return all the parts and I'm running out of time.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.  Mike

Comment: Once you're in the game, does it still run at 100%?  It's pretty normal for a game to use 100% CPU during launch.  It's doing a bunch of things that are CPUS intensive, and it wants to do those things as fast as it can.

Comment: Are you saying without an internet connection it doesn't run at 100%?

Comment: Can you confirm that it is Borderlands using all of the CPU and not some background process?

Answer (score 3):

A game using 100% of the CPU is not a bug, it is the intended behavior.

You're running a game, what else do you want the CPU to be used for? Any CPU a game can take helps increase your frame rate and is generally a good thing so game use as much as possible.

Comment: First of all, the game doesn't need to do EVERYTHING as fast as it can. Game world is simulated at a finite frame rate (I don't know for Borderlands, for Minecraft it is 20 ticks/second. Let's say 60 for BL.), and the only other intensive task is drawing the screen, which is 1) done on GPU, not CPU, 2) is also limited to 62 FPS by default. Second, an i5-4690K is a beast, and you need veeery heavy tasks to load it for 100% continuously - 3 year old game is definitely not enough.

Comment: In other words - how would a game at 270 FPS be better than 260 FPS? You stop seeing difference at around 100, and 60 is perfectly comfortable for your eyes.

Comment: Even ignoring the game logic you still need to update all animations, update the particles, sounds, extrapolate every entities position and more every frame. And how is it even relevant how good the CPU is? The game will take 100% of a core because that is what games do. Do note that the 100% also counts time *waiting for the GPU to finish*.

Comment: Updating particles and positioning every vertex is what GPU does. And writing the game in a way that forces the CPU to _wait for GPU, without being able to switch to other processes_, is as stupid as... I have no words! If I did something like that at my job, I'd not even get fired, people would wonder if I'm sick or went nuts. Let me give you another example: I have an i5-4210U, which is more than twice slower than i5-4690K, and BL2 only eats up 50-70% of my CPU at 60 FPS (and I repeat, 62 is the default FPS limit). On i5-4690K, the same game should only load the CPU for, like, 20-40%.

Comment: Uuh no, you are wrong, do some research. But this is getting to long for comments.

Comment: Sorry, Kevin, I have 20 years of experience as a gamer/modder and 6 years of software development for living to back me up. And you still didn't answer why having 270 FPS is better than 260.

Comment: Come to a chat sometimes to talk, comments aren't meant for discussions like this (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge or http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development are rooms I frequent where this would be on topic).